# Matching part of regex in substrings

Tags: regex

edit: see [Matching part of regex in substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836920/matching-part-of-regex-in-substrings?noredirect=1#comment105809048_59836920)

I don't know if title is good but let me give some examples.

this is the pattern i came up with:

```regex
/(---+\s*([^\s-]+)\s*---+)(.*?)(---+\s*[^\s-]+\s*---+)/gs
```

These are scenarios:

```
--- content ---

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
--- --- --- --- --- ---
Suspendisse nec dui in orci ullamcorper porttitor. 
Sed lobortis dui ut placerat tempor. Donec lacus nibh, porta vitae mattis ac, facilisis dictum ipsum.

--- content ---
```

```
--- sub-content 1 ---

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
--- --- --- --- --- ---
Suspendisse nec dui in orci ullamcorper porttitor. 
Sed lobortis dui ut placerat tempor. Donec lacus nibh, porta vitae mattis ac, facilisis dictum ipsum.

--- sub-content 1 ---
```

```
--- sub-content 1 2 3 ---

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
--- --- --- --- --- ---
Suspendisse nec dui in orci ullamcorper porttitor. 
Sed lobortis dui ut placerat tempor. Donec lacus nibh, porta vitae mattis ac, facilisis dictum ipsum.

--- sub-content 1 2 3 ---
```

I can match if space count known but couldnt figured out where space count between non-space characters unknown. Basically i want to match all strings as long as there is a non-space character between first and end `---XXX---`

Comment: Try `^(---+\s+(.*?)\s+---+)$(.*?)^(---+\s+\2\s+--+)$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nzQ4YL/1)

Comment: thanks for answer but it matches where there are only whitespace characters between `---`. Also it doesnt have to be same. I just want to match if there is a character other than whitespace

Comment: Then try `^(---+\s+([^\s-].*?)\s+---+)$(.*?)^(---+\s+([^\s-].*?)\s+--+)$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nzQ4YL/2)

Comment: thanks it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with a multiline flag (note you do not need any flag if you use the pattern in Ruby):

```
^(---+\s+([^\s-].*?)\s+---+)$(.*?)^(---+\s+([^\s-].*?)\s+--+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nzQ4YL/2). I added line start/end anchors `^` and `$` and changed `[^\s-]+` that did not allow any intraword hyphens to `[^\s-].*?` that requires a char other than whitespace and a hyphen and then anything up to the trailing hyphens.